# Does arbiter node in mongodb has admin database

Tags: mongodb, database-replication

I have set 3 MongoDB nodes in replication set - primary, secondary and arbiter.

I just want to know does arbiter node in Mongo Database has admin database by default when its configured.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The arbiter does not contain any data therefore you or the application won't need to authenticate if you connect directly.

When your application is connecting to a replicaset it will detect if a node is an arbiter and don't attempt to connect to it.

Depending on the driver there could be exceptions (bugs) where the application could still attempt to authenticate to the arbiter.